# Problems while porting Chrome extension to Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I try to port a chrome extension to Firefox.

The first error Firefox throws when adding the extension is the following:

```
Reading manifest: 
Warning processing background.persistent: Event pages are not currently supported. This will run as a persistent background page.
```

[image]

In the console the following error appears when the extension icon is clicked (-> started).

```
Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

That seems to happen on this part of the code

```
// Called when the user clicks on the chrome.action
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // Send a message to the active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {
                message: "clicked_chrome.action"
            });
    });
});
```

I suspect the issue of "Cannot establish connection" is, that some of the tabs I try to send a message to don't have the content.js script injected.

Any hints?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Dynalist Highlighter",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "192": "logo192.png",
    "512": "logo512.png"
  },
  "background" :{
  "scripts": ["/app/background.js"],
  "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {},
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "<all_urls>", "contextMenus", "tabs"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "/src/content.css",
    "/src/App.css",
    "/src/cssreset.css"
  ]
}
```

content.js injection: (source: background.js)
Runs when the user clicks the extension icon.

The extension is supported on tabs which support script injections. No about:... pages etc.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS({file: "/src/App.css"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            null,
            {file: "/src/content.js"},
            activateExtension
        );
});
```

Comment: 1) Firefox doesn't support event pages - the background script is always persistent - so make sure your code and its logic are ready for this. 2) the error message means there was no content script running in the tab and indeed your manifest.json doesn't specify any. In case you run them via executeScript you should show the relevant code and describe **when** it runs relative to the browserAction click. Note that some URLs are not injectable e.g. the built-in UI, 3) query() is not needed in onClicked: simply use `tab` parameter.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. This helps a lot. I will try to adapt the code and see if it works. Yes I run the content script via executeScript when the user clicks the extension icon. I added the code to my question.

Comment: Okay you where right I tried to message the content script before it was executet with executeScript. For some reason the error still persists.